# How to merge multi-dimensional array into single array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have array which conatins (MANY) assoc arrays with values. I want to merge those nested arrays into single array. I tried `call_user_func_array('array_merge', $bigArray)`, but this will write into same keys, since they are assoc and they repeat. So I need something that ignores array keys and just merges values.

My array:

```
[
    ['a' => 'aaa', 'b' => 'bbb', 'c' => 'ccc'],
    ['a' => 'ddd', 'b' => 'eee', 'c' => 'fff'],
]
```

Desired result:

```
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee', 'fff']
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question has been already answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array

Comment: `array_values(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array))`

Comment: array_walk looks great! Thank you

Comment: @deceze i changed "my array"...

Answer (score 1):

```
$newArr = array();
foreach ($bigArray as $tmp) {
  $newArr = array_merge($newArr, array_values($tmp));
}

// $newArr holds your desired data
print_r($newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_reduce`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) in conjunction with `array_values` and `array_merge`:

```
$result = array_reduce($array, function ($r, $v) {
    return $r = array_merge($r, array_values($v));
});
```